# VLOOKUP in Python with JSON or CSV

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have two data sources available in JSON and CSV.
The 1st JSON looks like:

```
[
 {
   "Number": "AA23LA13-14",
   "Status": "S"
 },
 {
   "Number": "AA23LA14-18",
   "Status": "F"
 },
 {
   "Number": "AA23LA14-22",
   "Status": "F"
 },
 {
   "Number": "AA23LA14-9",
   "Status": "F"
 },
 {
   "Number": "AA23LA18S-30",
   "Status": "F"
 },
 {
   "Number": "AA23LB-11",
   "Status": "F"
 },`
 ...
```

The CSV equivalent is:

```
Number;Status
AA23LA13-14;S
AA23LA14-18;F
AA23LA14-22;F
AA23LA14-9;F
AA23LA18S-30;F
AA23LB-11;F
...
```

There are 151.815 rows in the CSV file.
The 2nd soruce in JSON looks like:

```
[
 {
   "Number": "#901",
   "State": "Released"
 },
 {
   "Number": "07559-03046",
   "State": "Released"
 },
 {
   "Number": "07559-03046",
   "State": "Released"
 },
 {
   "Number": "07612-02001",
   "State": "Obsolete"
 },
 {
   "Number": "07612-02001",
   "State": "Obsolete"
 },
 {
   "Number": "07612-02001",
   "State": "Obsolete"
 },
 ...
```

and in CSV:

```
Number;State
#901;Released
07559-03046;Released
07559-03046;Released
07612-02001;Obsolete
...
```

The 2nd CSV has 537.123 rows.

The following relations between the two sources are:

- Number = Number
- Status = State

How can I use python the most efficient way, to compare the files (JSON or CSV) and search the number of the 1st source in the 2nd source and if there is a match, add the State from the first source to the object of the 2nd source.

E.g.:

```
[
 {
   "Number": "#901",
   "State": "Released"
   "Status": "F"
 },
 {
   "Number": "07559-03046",
   "State": "Released"
   "Status": "F"
 },
 ...
```

Comment: Are the `Number` elements from both json and csv file being considered as unique? Your csv snippet contains duplicate entries for `07559-03046`. If these elements are unique, you can load each file into a pandas DataFrame, drop duplicates, set each index to the `number` column and perform a map or join/merge upon the index to get a summarizing dataframe containing all data you want to have. Then you can extract the data you are interested in.

Comment: Sounds complicated. The numbers should be unique. Of they are not, I need to update the report. Thus the code can handle numbers uniquely. But for sure there are not unique for both files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are dealing with a big number of rows, I would suggest using [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/). Then you can do the following:

1. Import each of your data sources (as [`csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) or [`json`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html) files) into an individual [`DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html)
2. Assuming `Number` being unique, you can set this as the index (to ensure this, you could call [`.drop_duplicates()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) beforehand).
3. Use the second dataframe to perform a lookup based on the number (which is the same in both dataframes). You can do this in different ways, one of them is to perform a [`.map()` on the index](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.map.html).
4. Assign the lookup result as a new column to the first dataframe

This might sound a bit complex, but can be done in just a few lines:

```
import random
import string

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# generate some sample data
numbers = np.random.randint(500, size=20)
states = random.choices(string.ascii_uppercase, k=4)
status = random.choices(string.ascii_uppercase, k=4)

# combine a Number and a State to create a dummy of your first data souce
first_source = pd.DataFrame(
    [{'Number': n, 'State': random.choice(states)} for n in numbers]
)

# combine a Number and a Status to create a dummy of your second data souce
second_source = pd.DataFrame(
    [{'Number': n, 'Status': random.choice(status)} for n in numbers]
)

# you would need to import your data sources into pandas dataframes
# Since I generated some sample data using the code above, I do not need to do this, but
# using csv files would basically look like this (adopt to your needs)
# first_source = pd.read_csv('first_soruce.csv')
# second_source = pd.read_csv('first_soruce.csv')

# as Number is considered being unique, we can drop all duplicate entries (checking `Number` column only) ans set the index to this column
first_source = first_source.drop_duplicates(subset='Number').set_index('Number')
second_source = second_source.drop_duplicates(subset='Number').set_index('Number')

# we can now use the index of `first_source` to lookup the according `Status` value from `second_source` and assign in to a new column `Status`
# `first_source` will then contain all information (from both data sources) and can be used for further processing or to export the information
first_source['Status'] = first_source.index.map(lambda x: second_source.loc[x].iloc[0])
print(first_source)
```